# XDocument Load on Inherited Class - Unable to cast

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, but until I hit this problem it seemed a fairly elegant way to implement my requirement, I have a load of xpath based code that modifies a word document. It's pretty old and I am upgrading it now to make it more manageable while adding some extra functionality.

I thought, it would make sense to make a DocxDocument class and have it inherit the XDocument class so I can use System.Xml.Linq and System.Xml.Xpath to edit the underlying xml document.

I wrongly thought, that XDocument could be cast as DocXDocument if it inherited the type. So, looking at the code below how the hell do I load and XDocument to a DocXDocument?

```
Public Class DocXDocument2
    Inherits XDocument

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Function Load(DocumentPath As String) As XDocument
        Using pkg = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocumentPath, True)
            Return XDocument.Load(pkg.MainDocumentPart.GetStream())
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

I just want to be able to load the doc something like:

```
dim docx = DocXDocument.load("C:\temp.docx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is: You don't overwrite the `XDocument`. You rather create a wrapper around the `XDocument` that stores the reference to the loaded document and allows you do access it in the way you want to. I **highly** recommend doing it like this.

Your class could look like this:

```
Public Class DocXDocument2
    Private ReadOnly _doc As XDocument

    Private Sub New(doc As XDocument)
        _doc = doc
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(DocumentPath As String) As XDocument
        Using pkg = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocumentPath, True)
            Return New DocXDocument2(XDocument.Load(pkg.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function Descendants As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        Return _doc.Descendants 
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that the original `XDocument` exposes the load function as a `Shared` function. So I changed that here.

How ever there is a way to get it done with inheritance. But it is not pretty. You have to `Shadow` the load method to force your method to be used and you have to use the Copy-Constructor of `XDocument` to get your document in properly. So it could look like this:

```
Public Class DocXDocument2
    Inherits XDocument

    Private Sub New(doc As XDocument)
        MyBase.New(doc)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Shadows Function Load(DocumentPath As String) As XDocument
        Using pkg = WordprocessingDocument.Open(DocumentPath, True)
            Return New DocXDocument2(XDocument.Load(pkg.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

This is only for the sake of sticking as close to your approach as possible. I really recommend to use the first method. It is cleaner code and it gives you better control over what is done with the document and what is not. Inheriting `XDocument` after all exposes every single `public` method of `XDocument` to who ever uses your class.

To your initial question, why the cast of `XDocument` to `DocXDocument2` failed. The reason simply is that the `XDocument.Load` function creates a `XDocument` and not a `DocXDocument2`. You can easily cast a instance of a specific class to any class or interface that is implemented by the object. But you can't cast it to a object that narrows the implementation of the specific object. You have to construct the instance as a `DocXDocument2` to get a instance of this type.

Comment: Thank you bud, top class answer - I think in this case I will use your second example as I have already put a load more code in aiming for this method, and I am kind of enjoying using vb.net's xml capabilities like Me...<w:p>! :-)

Comment: You have been warned ;-) But this is the reason why I provided both examples. Please don't forget marking the answer.

Comment: Already marked as answer, out of interest within the first example if I wanted to edit the xml I would just have to to _doc.descendants etc instead of Me.descendants?

Comment: Marking the answer works with the tick below the voting control ;-) And yes: This is the way how you would access properties. But for better access you could also define properties in your new class that forward to the property in the document.

Comment: I added a example for such a forwarding function. This is what I meant with the additional control over what you expose and what you don't expose.

Comment: Sorry I was sure I had pressed accept, apparently not when I refreshed!